# when i use yarn create-react-app i get 'C:\Program' is not recognized as the internal or external program

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I tried to remove the global create-react-app using both yarn remove and npm uninstall but still can't initialize a react app using yarn I even uninstall yarn and install it again but I'm stuck in the same problem

Comment: have you checked https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6512 ??

Comment: i did the answers there didn't slove this